# Adjoint vs Self-adjoint operators represented by matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

I want to see the difference between just adjoint and self-adjoint (hermitian) operator represented by matrices.

If I have a matrix $$A=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & i \\
    i & 1  \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
then its conjugate is

$$A^*=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -i \\
    -i & 1  \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$ ?

Or what are the properties of just adjoint matrices?

The Hermitian matrix is for example: $$A=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -i \\
    i & 1  \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

because its conjugate transpose equals to $A$.

I am very confused as I saw just the definitions of adjoint operators via scalar product, like this: $[Ax,y] = [x,A^*y]$ but I cannot think about an example to get intuition even though my question probably is pretty obvious.

Comment: We can express the complex inner product $\langle u, v\rangle$ as the matrix product $u^*v$. This shows why the conjugate transpose is the adjoint: $(Ax)^*y=x^*A^*y$.

Comment: I somehow thought that the adjoint operator matrix is just the conjugate of the matrix but forgot about the trasposition (in my example is the matrix symmetric), so I think I know where I did a mistake. Thanks.